# Get Manager Chain based on passed user using Azure Graph APIs

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am looking to call a graph api that returns the manager chain for a provided user. Looking for something like in the below URL:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/user-list-manager.md

Based on the above example, I was trying to call the api as below:

https://graph.windows.net/OrganizationName/users/test@test.com/?api-version=123456&$expand=manager($levels=12)&$count=true

I am getting response as below:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/---url",
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.User",
    "objectType": "User",
    "objectId": "f7f6a1g1-7291-78fb-7aq1-90c509092209",
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "assignedLicenses": [],
    "assignedPlans": [],
    "city": "Phoenix",
    "country": null,
    "department": "Dev Department",
    "dirSyncEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "Test Test",
    "facsimileTelephoneNumber": null,
    "givenName": "",
    "immutableId": "12345",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "lastDirSyncTime": "2021-01-27T00:02:55Z",
    "mail": "test@test.com",
    "mailNickname": "test",
    "mobile": null,
    "otherMails": [],
    "passwordPolicies": "",
    "passwordProfile": null,
    "physicalDeliveryOfficeName": "",
    "postalCode": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "provisionedPlans": [],
    "provisioningErrors": [],
    "proxyAddresses": [],
    "state": null,
    "streetAddress": null,
    "surname": "",
    "telephoneNumber": null,
    "thumbnailPhoto@odata.mediaEditLink": "",
    "usageLocation": "US",
    "userPrincipalName": "test@test.com",
    "userType": "Member"
}
```

But I don't see the manager name anywhere. How can I get the manager chain?

Comment: There is no select statement specifying which properties you want back in the API call. Try adding $select=manager to the end. Here is documentation about select queries that may help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

`$expand=manager` is used for [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). It looks like this, you could test it in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id or userPrincipalName}/?$expand=manager($levels=12)&$count=true
```

It seems a Rest API in your issue that does not support [$expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter).

Comment: How can I change the access token in Graph Explorer? I want to provide my access token in it to see if my URL works over there.

Comment: from the Graph Explorer, I could get the manager data using expand. But it fetches only one level of data. I see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues link where it say the expand doesn't support more than one level. Does that mean that I need to make multiple calls to go till root level?

Comment: Another question is, I tried expand for manager in Graph Explorer, which returned the manager level data. But if I use the same from my local, it doesn't return manager level data. The difference I made for the request URL. In Graph Explorer, I used "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=id)&$select=id&$count=true". But from my local, I used "https://graph.windows.net/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/users/test@test.com?api-version=123456&$expand=manager($levels=max)&$count=true". Local one doesn't return manager details but the Graph Explorer one does. Please help.

Comment: The $expand is used for **Microsoft Graph API**, but you use the older [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog) in your local.